# How to read the cookie value in response in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I m sending a request to the server ,for that im getting RSA key ,along with that some cookie value will be sent to client side to set the session.But i dont know to read the cookie value to set the session?
Someone please help me...
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Reading cookie at side is quite simple. You can just read the cookie with the cookie name. Lets say you have set the cookie with some name lets say 
`testCookie`

Then you fetch the cookie with the document method

```
let getCookie = function (cname) {
    let name = cname + "=";
    let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
            return c.indexOf(name);
        }
    }
}
```

So now to fetch the cookie, you can call `getCookie('testCookie')`

Hope this helps

Comment: what im asking is that Im getting response along with that a cookie will be sent to client side.Im not setting name for cookie.Im getting cookie from client side and i need to read that cookie..

Comment: I believe cookies are always stored at client side. Not sure what exactly you want to try.

Comment: What i mean is ,cookie coming from server side, (let's say) i want to print it..i dont know that in what name its coming....If u want me to explain more,I ll do..N i m very new to angular...

Comment: If cookie is coming with secured code you wont be able to read it. Angular automatically sends that information if you make a request